# How to get custom User data in Stormpath with expressJS?

Tags: json, node.js, express, user-data, stormpath

Hi I want to get a custom JSON file from the stormpath API in a normal JS function instead of within a view.

The view method is like this:

```
var stormpath = require('express-stormpath');
app.get('/email', stormpath.loginRequired, function(req, res) {
res.send('Your email address is:', res.locals.user);
});
```

However when I attempt to just use the method like this:

```
var customD = res.send('Your email address is:', res.locals.user);
```

it returns an unexpected token ' ( ' error

Comment: don't really understand what you want to achieve

Comment: I want to retrieve users information if they ask for it opposed to when the user is in a particular view.

Answer (score 2):

In the posted example the quotation marks `’` are a rich encoded, not the standard single `'` or double quotes `"`.  I would replace your quotes with single quotes.  What text editor are you using to write your node application?

Regarding the original question about custom data, can you show us how you are assigning the custom data properties?  I suspect that you might have run into this issue: https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-node/issues/88

Comment: sorry about that fixed it there. Not that it really matters but I use sublime to write almost everything.

Comment: I fixed the commas after I pasted in the code thats all. I'm still stumped.

Comment: Regarding the unexpected token error:  could you possibly show us some more of the code for this app?  From those snippets above I don't see how the assignment of customD would cause a token error, so I wonder what else is going on in the application?

Comment: everything else works a charm. I literally just added this and was tinkering with it to get it to work but it fails to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following code sample?

```
var stormpath = require('express-stormpath');
app.get('/email', stormpath.loginRequired, function(req, res) {
  res.send('Your email address is:' + res.locals.user.email);
});
```

I suspect a few things:

- Your code is running OUTSIDE of a route.
- You have a comma in res.send(), so the send method thinks you're passing in additional arguments as opposed to a single string.
- You're not using the email address directly.

Comment: That is what I posted above. I would rather do this operation outside of a route if possible.

Comment: Ah, ok. In that case you need to use the RAW Stormpath Node library: https://www.npmjs.org/package/stormpath If you install this, then you can use it directly to do whatever you'd like -- but you have to fetch user accounts manually, create a client manually, etc. The Express library can only be used to do stuff INSIDE Of a route.

Comment: ok so I went downloaded the package and followed the docs as prescribed https://www.npmjs.org/package/stormpath                       but i'm still probably more lost now than I was. my user already signs in using stormpath and routing is there no way that I can nab their account information like their account href or better still load in their custom data to an array and then use it later?

Comment: So, if you're outside of a route, there's no way to 'detect' the user -- you have to look it up manually (as if you were writing a command line program). The concept of 'users' only exists within an incoming web request (a route).

Comment: so would the thing to do be to detect a unique user route when they sign in and make stormpath requests from there?